# Teradata query optimisation

Tags: sql, optimization, teradata, where-clause, sql-delete

I need to select a group of people from the database with some conditions using Teradata SQL Assistant. Which of the following methods is faster and why:

Method A

```
Create volatile table selection as ( 
Select * 
from table_a
Where id not in (sel id from table_b)
And id not in (sel id from table_c)
And id not in (sel id from table_d)
...
) With data primary index (id) on commit preserve rows;
```

Method B

```
Create volatile table selection as ( 
Select * 
from table_a
) With data primary index (id) on commit preserve rows;
Delete from selection where id in (sel id from table_b);
Delete from selection where id in (sel id from table_c);
Delete from selection where id in (sel id from table_d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test *whatever* query on your data and your database.

I would expect `not exists` to perform a bit better:

```
Select a.* 
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1 from table_b b where b.id = a.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from table_c c where c.id = a.id) and
      not exists (select 1 from table_d d where d.id = a.id) ;
```

In particular, this can make use of indexes on `table_b(id)`, `table_c(id)`, and `table_d(id)`.  In addition, the semantics are clearer.  `NOT IN` with subqueries can return (or not return!) strange results when the subquery returns `NULL`.

That said, I would expect getting the query right to be faster than creating the table and then removing rows.  The latter would seem to involve lots of "make-work" -- adding rows into a table just to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon wrote, if those ids are defined as NULLable, NOT EXISTS will outperform NOT IN. Otherwise they're equal, simply compare Explains.

Those three subqueries will be translated to three joins, another solution using a single join only:

```
Create volatile table selection as ( 
Select * 
from table_a
Where id not in 
 ( sel id from table_b 
   union all
   sel id from table_c
   union all
   sel id from table_d
 )
...
) With data primary index (id) on commit preserve rows;
```

Pf course, performance also depends on number of rows per table and existing indexes.